# Undefined reference when using boost on WSL (Bash On Windows)

Tags: c++, boost, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use program_options from Boost in my project.

I am using Windows 10 but compiling on the ubuntu subsystem using g++.

I installed on boost using `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev` and then proceeded to try out their example file found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/program_options/example/first.cpp).

Then I compiled using `g++ first.cpp` and received the following error:

```
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `main':
first.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
first.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
first.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allo
cator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
first.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::add_options()'
first.cpp:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, char const*)'
first.cpp:(.text+0xea): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char
const*)'
first.cpp:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::variables_map::variables_map()'
first.cpp:(.text+0x159): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> const&, boost::program_options::variables_map&, b
ool)'
first.cpp:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::notify(boost::program_options::variables_map&)'
first.cpp:(.text+0x20b): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::~error_with_option_name()':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameD2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameD5Ev]+0x10): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::pr
ogram_options::error_with_option_name'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::ch
ar_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_error
C5ENS1_6kind_tERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_i]+0x3d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template[abi:cxx11](boost::
program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_error
C5ENS1_6kind_tERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_i]+0x5b): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(st
d::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::
__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::value_semantic_codecvt_helper()':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options29value_semantic_codecvt_helperIcEC2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options29value_semantic_codecvt_helperIcEC5Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `
vtable for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::~value_semantic_codecvt_helper()':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options29value_semantic_codecvt_helperIcED2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options29value_semantic_codecvt_helperIcED5Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `v
table for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const':
first.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKNSt7__cxx1112ba
sic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<
char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x81): undefined reference to
 `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_
string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::options(boost::program_options::options_description const&)':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE7optionsERKNS0_19options_descriptionE[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE7optionsERKN
S0_19options_descriptionE]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_options_description(boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::style(int)':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE5styleEi[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE5styleEi]+0x1c): undefined reference to `
boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::style(int)'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::extra_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<ch
ar>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::alloc
ator<char> > const&>)':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE12extra_parserENS_9function1ISt4pairINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_ERKSA_EE[_ZN5b
oost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE12extra_parserENS_9function1ISt4pairINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_ERKSA_EE]+0x42): undefined reference
 to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_additional_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std
::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>)'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::run()':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE3runEv[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE3runEv]+0x28): undefined reference to `boos
t::program_options::detail::cmdline::get_canonical_option_prefix()'
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE3runEv[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE3runEv]+0x54): undefined reference to `boos
t::program_options::detail::cmdline::run()'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::cha
r_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > boost::program_options::to_internal<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::vector<std::_
_cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const
&)':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESt6vectorIS7_SaIS7_EERKS8_IT_SaISB_EE[_ZN5boost15program_options11to
_internalINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESt6vectorIS7_SaIS7_EERKS8_IT_SaISB_EE]+0x6c): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__cx
x11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::valu
e_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic
_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_opt
ions::error_with_option_name::what() const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_opt
ions::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::er
ror_with_option_name::what() const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::er
ror_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcEE[_ZTIN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::program_
options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTIN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::progra
m_options::error_with_option_name'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::~variables_map()':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options13variables_mapD2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options13variables_mapD5Ev]+0xe): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::vari
ables_map'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<double, char>::name() const':
first.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcE4nameEv]+0x41): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::ar
g[abi:cxx11]'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `void boost::program_options::validate<double, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<
char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, double*, long)':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateIdcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT0_St11char_traitsIS7_ESaIS7_EEESaISB_EEPT_l[_ZN5boost15program_options8va
lidateIdcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT0_St11char_traitsIS7_ESaIS7_EEESaISB_EEPT_l]+0x44): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validators::check_f
irst_occurrence(boost::any const&)'
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateIdcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT0_St11char_traitsIS7_ESaIS7_EEESaISB_EEPT_l[_ZN5boost15program_options8va
lidateIdcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT0_St11char_traitsIS7_ESaIS7_EEESaISB_EEPT_l]+0x141): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_val
ue::invalid_option_value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o: In function `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(boost::program_options::error_with_option_name const&)':
first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameC2ERKS1_[_ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameC5ERKS1_]+0x25): undefined reference to `vtable for b
oost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implI
NS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implI
NS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::
__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15progr
am_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15progr
am_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_
traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_i
mplINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_i
mplINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholde
rs(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15p
rogram_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
/tmp/cc9iLK5U.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15p
rogram_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, st
d::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure if I missed a step or is it something related to WSL it self.

Comment: You need to link it with the appropriate boost libraries as well.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the problem is not related to WSL. I just had to add the appropriate links:

`c++ first.cpp -lboost_program_options`